# Do not let unregistered users “comment everywhere” (at least on certain sites)

Tags: feature-request, comments, privileges, unregistered-users

#### Proposal

Implement the following on all sites or make it an opt-in feature (for comment-heavy sites or sites suffering from answers in comments):
Do not grant unregistered users the [comment everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege, i.e., prevent them from commenting except on their own posts (including answers to their questions).

#### Rationale

In my understanding unregistered users mainly exist to provide a low threshold for people to engage with the site, e.g., to post an answer to a question when every other answer is wrong. Activities that reflect a deeper involvement such as voting or posting on meta are not available to unregistered users.
In my opinion, commenting reflects such a deeper involvement.

Now, most unregistered users are not affected by the proposed change since they never reach the respective reputation or are one-hit wonders who do not venture outside their own post(s).
Those who are affected are usually those who stay unregistered as a matter of principle or due to laziness.
In my experience, these are often serial unregistered users, i.e., users who start a fresh unregistered account every now and then (e.g., when they lost their cookie).

Allowing unregistered users to comment everywhere has the following disadvantage:

- It is more difficult to spot and rectify bad comment patterns (such as serial answers in comments or borderline rudeness), since they span multiple accounts.
  One of serial unregistered user on a site I moderate tended to post answers until they reached 50 reputation and then mostly posted answers in comments.
  Of course, if somebody uses a series of unregistered accounts with the intention to evade moderation, they can still do the same with registered accounts, but I doubt that that’s the motivation in most cases.
- These users are more likely to use comments in lieu of votes or other privileges they lack due to not registering.
  For example, I recently spotted a case of a serial unregistered user who left a considerable amount of +1 comments (that were aptly disguised to go under the automatic radars).
- Many good comments (i.e., comments used as intended) exist to be potentially replied to, e.g., to inform the commenter that they have become obsolete.
  A serial unregistered user may however have moved to the next account when the reply comes.
  Of course, this is a problem with questions and answers as well (whose author if unregistered may never see the notification caused by a comment), but that’s more or less unavoidable if we want unregistered users to be able to do anything at all.

On all sites where I can judge this, I am quite confident that these disadvantages outweigh the advantage of the occasional pearl of a comment posted by such a user, but I acknowledge the possibility that this may not be the case everywhere.

Comment: Why only certain sites? What would be the criteria?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: See my first sentence: I would expect implementing this to be most beneficial on comment-heavy sites.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the 2nd point, can't an unregistered account at rep 15 upvote whereas it takes 50 to comment? Plus I'm not sure pointing out a comment is obsolete using another comment is a good use of them, shouldn't it just be a "no longer needed" flag?

Comment: @PeterJ: *can't an unregistered account at rep 15 upvote […]?* – No, unregistered users [cannot vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-register). — *I'm not sure pointing out a comment is obsolete using another comment is a good use of comment* – It depends. As the system is now, posters are not informed if their comment is flagged as obsolete, so there is no other way to do this. I would definitely consider something like “I tried to clarify. Please check whether it makes sense to you now.” a valid use of a comment.